# anyone know of javascript version of layout program like QuarkXpress?

Tags: website-design

anyone know of javascript version of layout program like QuarkXpress?

this would be browser-based tool that would have all the powerful and WYSIWYG accessible design and control tools like QuarkXpress

I've found some portions of the functions written in javascript, but not an entire package.

My searches of open source sites and web searches have mostly led to sites like this on stackexchange.

any suggestions appreciated (maybe I'll have to re-assemble the QuarkXpress "wheel" in javascript?)
Greg

PS
I just found a hopeful candidate program 
- Lucid £34.99 The escapers "designed to help you code JavaScript-powered sites in a simpler graphical interface" found via http://mac.appstorm.net
12-6-13

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! I wouldn't get my hopes up if I were you. Google Docs can't even export a document reliably, and...they're Google. If you do find something or come up with something I'd definitely be interested in seeing it!

Comment: Maybe Google Docs?

Comment: Or MS's web based Office suite?